# Delayed Code Changes Reflection in Docker on macOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We're a team of three developers working on a project using Docker, and we all use MacBooks. Interestingly, two team members don't encounter any issues, but I've been experiencing a peculiar problem with my Docker setup.

Initially, when I run docker compose up -d, everything works fine. However, after a certain point, the changes I make to the code start to exhibit delays in being reflected inside the Docker container. Eventually, the changes stop reflecting entirely, requiring me to restart the entire Docker environment using docker compose down followed by docker compose up -d.

I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including wiping my laptop, reinstalling everything from scratch, and experimenting with the new docker compose watch feature. Unfortunately, none of these attempts have resolved the issue.

The issue temporarily (for an hour or so) disappears when laptop is restarted. Then same cycle happens.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone else in the community has faced a similar problem or if there are suggestions on how to diagnose and fix this issue. Additionally, I'm wondering if there might be something in my Docker Compose file that could be contributing to this behavior.

Any insights or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Docker Compose version 2.24.1
Here is my docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: example/app
    ports:
      - '${LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT:-6001}:${LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT:-6001}'
      - "80:80"
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/example-dev
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      overwatch:
        aliases:
          - example
      example-net:
  mysql:
    image: "${DB_IMAGE}"
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - example_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      overwatch:
        aliases:
          - example_db
      example-net:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - example_redis:/data
    networks:
      - example-net
networks:
  example-net:
    driver: "bridge"
  overwatch:
    external: true
    name: overwatch
volumes:
  example_redis:
    driver: "local"
  example_mysql:
    driver: "local"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by changing from gRPC FUSE TO VirtioFS in Docker settings. Not sure what this changed, but my code changes are now updating properly

[image]